# How does the useEffect hook implemented outside the App component get executed everytime the searchTerm value is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

the custom hook 'useSemiPersistenceState' is implemented outside the App component including the useEffect hook

```
const useSemiPersistentState = (key, initialState) => {  

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(localStorage.getItem(key) || initialState); 

        React.useEffect(
         () => {
          localStorage.setItem(key, value); 
           },
         [value, key],
          );
       return [value, setValue]; 
     };
```

the custom hook is executed only once when the App component is mounted for the first time , so how the local storage set the new value of SearchTerm (from input field) when it gets updated by the setSearchTerm ?

```
  const App = () => {

     const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useSemiPersistentState('search', 'React');


     const handleSeach = (event) => {                
       setSearchTerm(event.target.value); 
     };
...
}
```

Comment: Where is this hook from? Is it from a third party library?

Comment: Perhaps [React's documentation on the `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook could help?

Comment: no it is not from a third party library

Comment: @cbr: I understand the concept of the useEffect hook in general, I just don't get this scenario

Comment: The effect runs every time the `useState` hook's value changes (or the key changes). When the effect  runs, it updates the value in the local storage. When setSearchTerm is called to update the state, the state's value changes. Which runs the effect.

Comment: @cbr: thank you for your answer but I already understand this .. but this time the UseEffect hook is outside the App Component , and useSemiPersistentState which contains the UseEffect  , is called only  when the component is mounted for the first time

Comment: That doesn't matter. Even though the useState and useEffect calls happen inside a different function, from React's point of view they both happen inside the App component so it's the same as if you'd just copypaste those hooks from useSemiPersistentState into App. This is mentioned in the section [How does a custom Hook get isolated state?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) So when the state inside usePersistentState changes, App re-renders which calls usePersistentState again, which leads to the useEffect hook being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the component loads for the first time, initial state is passed in the 'value' variable and the same is stored in the local storage also. The 'value here is basically the search keyword you are going to use so when in the second snippet the usePersistentState() is called its initial value is set to 'react'. But also at the same line is an example of [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). So when setSearchTerm is called snippet 2, the 'value' variable gets updated in usePersistentState and useEffect is triggered as it gets triggered if 'value' variable changes and same gets update in local storage.

In short, the 'value' variable is searchTerm when usePersistentState is called or triggered and hence the whole flow is working on that premise.